# Push delta changes on azure sql data warehouse from azure data lake gen 2 using azure databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I have been trying to use Azure Databricks to push changes happening at azure data lake (source) to azure SQL data warehouse (destination). If someone could help to list down the steps involved and how can it be achieved?

Also I would want to put it across in a very cost efficient way like the cluster should create/start and delete/stop at run-time. Will I require a job to do it?

Please let me know!

Comment: What are the changes? what is happening in data lake? Please consider adding more details so that we can help.

Comment: I have chosen a basic .CSV file. Changes such as insert/delete/update happening on source side will only be reflected on destination side when the job runs. Thats delta changes basically. So any idea how can i go about it?